# Como fazer um ListView com componentes ao lado do texto em cada linha?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-layout

Vários sistemas Androids atuais tem os menus como o do exemplo abaixo:

[image: acesso desligado]

Reparem que em qualquer lugar que eu tocar com o dedo na área azul em "Acesso a minha localização" ele liga ou desliga o *switch* e habilita ou desabilita o bloco em "Fontes de Localização", e também faz o efeito azul no bloco clicado.

[image: encostando na tela para ligar o acesso]

Sem conhecer muito bem as opções que o Android me oferece eu tentei fazer algo igual, quer seria a base do que eu realmente pretendo fazer. Fiz o seguinte código:

**activity.xml**

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lstSegundaTela"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

**MinhaActivity.java**

```
lstSegundaTela = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstSegundaTela);
List<Map<String, String>> dados = new ArrayList<>();
String[] valores = new String[] {
        "Acesso a minha localização",
        "Satélite de GPS",
        "Local de rede móvel e Wi-Fi"};
String[] descricoes = new String[] {
        "Permitir que os aplicativos que solicitaram sua permissão " +
        "usem seus dados de localização",
        "Permitir que os aplicativos usem o GPS do telefone para " +
        "determinar sua posição",
        "Permitir que os aplicativos usem o serviço de localização " +
        "do Google para determinar seu local mais rapidamente. Dados " +
        "de localização anônimos serão coletados e enviados ao Google"};
for(int i=0; i<valores.length; i++) {
    Map<String, String> linha = new HashMap<>();
    dados.add(linha);
    linha.put("Titulo", valores[i]);
    linha.put("Subtitulo", descricoes[i]);
}
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
        this,
        dados,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
        new String[] {"Titulo", "Subtitulo"},
        new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
lstSegundaTela.setAdapter(adapter);
```

O resultado foi o seguinte:

[image: resultado do meu código]

Minhas dúvidas são:

- Como colocar componentes do tipo Switch e CheckBox na linha do ListView conforme exemplo acima?
- Como foi criado o bloco "Fontes de Localização"? Ou ele seria um outro ListView com um título?

Comment: Pode verificar aqui: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Foi lá que eu vi para chegar até onde eu cheguei, depois disso empaquei. Lá tem um exemplo com CheckBox no ListView, mas não conforme o exemplo que eu mostrei acima.

Comment: Isso é simples, basta criar um item no xml com um `TextView` e uma `Checkbox`, e depois usar esse item na `ListView`.

Comment: @Math, esses componentes se chamam Preferences (de uma olhada em  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html), os titulos são headers da PreferenceCategory. Se não for isso que quer de uma olhada nesse tutorial do Cyril Mottier: http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/11/23/listview-tips-tricks-4-add-several-clickable-areas/

Comment: @JorgeB. você quer dizer que eu montaria um template para usar para cada linha? Daí eu poderia por exemplo fazer dois TextView (um com fonte grande e outro com fonte pequena) e junto colocar um componente. Já não existe algo pronto para fazer isso?

Comment: @Wakim vou olhar sim. Obrigado.

Comment: Olha a minha resposta. Se quiseres mais um TextView para o titulo é só adicionar também no XML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isso é simples, basta criar um item no XML com um `TextView` e uma `Checkbox`, e depois usar esse item na `ListView`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## ItemList layout:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

       <CheckBox
            android:id="@+item/radioButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:checked="false"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+item/descObs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="20dp" 
            android:text="check"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**NOTA:**
Repara que a `TextView` também é selecionável:

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

---

## No Teu Adaptador é só chamar o *layout* como outro qualquer:

```
public class TeuAdaptador extends ArrayAdapter<TeuObjeto> {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public TeuAdaptador(
            Context contexto,
            List<TeuObjeto> listObj) {

        super(contexto, R.layout.teu_item_xml, listObj);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(contexto);

    }

    //os teus métodos, getView, etc
    ...
}
```

**PS:**

Já agora aconselho-te a ter as *string's* todas em `res/values-pt/strings.xml` como *resource*:

```
<resources>

    <string name="a_minha_string">Esta é a minha string</string>
```

e depois usar `context.getString(R.string.a_minha_string)` para ir buscar a mesma.

Comment: Como criar o XML ok. Mas qual seria o tipo de adaptador para colocar no ListView? Em outras palavras, como usar esse XML como item do ListView?

Comment: Vê a minha edição, não percebi bem se era isso que querias.

Comment: Vê também o PS que pus agora. Vai-te facilitar a vida.

Comment: Ok, tens também as *preferences* que o @Wakim enumerou, mas eu prefiro fazer tudo a mão mesmo, para ganhar pratica e para poder fazer o que quiser, sem me preocupar com restrições.

Comment: Ah, os Preferences são mais usados como Settings, como na imagem, além disso é feito de forma manual sem adapter. A principio dessa forma funciona, apesar de ter problema se precisar capturar cliques individualmente e não apenas na linha inteira.

Comment: Como a minha pergunta foi "Como fazer um ListView com componentes ao lado do texto em cada linha?" sua resposta está correta, funciona :) mas para o meu caso atual acho que vai ser mais fácil usar o Preferences, rs.. Mesmo assim obrigado pela resposta, me ajudou.